# Can't boot ubuntu form usb anymore after breaking current installation

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I had Ubuntu running on my Microsoft Surface, but hat some issues with the touch screen and wanted to reinstall the Surface Kernel. Unfortunately I forgot to update Grub and I assume that broke my installation. But now I simply can't boot into an usb with Ubuntu on it anymore. It doesn't get past the mainboard logo and is just stuck there, while other distros like Arch seem to work fine and also Windows is bootable form my usb.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you boot another computer from that USB drive? Are you booting in UEFI mode? And in that case, are you using Secure boot? The update might has imposed stricter or updated rules, so that you need a new certificate in the boot system on the USB drive. You can test with the newest version, 23.10,  of Ubuntu (or a corresponding Ubuntu flavour, for example the lightweight Lubuntu or Xubuntu). I can boot the newest PC computers, that I can access, with Lubuntu 23.10.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a usb-stick with a 'super_grub2_disk_hybrid_' iso (https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/). You can use an old stick you have as it is a very small .iso ( around 20 MiB ). When starting up/booting this stick it will scan all the bootable systems you have on your system. Then boot into 'Ubuntu' and do a grub update ( when booted in Ubuntu open a terminal (press Ctrl + Alt + T at the same time), in the terminal type `sudo update-grub` , wait for the update to finish). 
Reboot your computer.